# No error in gradle.build none while compiling but the app keeps crashing everytime

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, manifest

Manifest file is showing error on 6th line, cant really figure out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFToX.jpg)

tried updating dependencies

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The property `android:name` should not begin with a dot: `(.Noteapp & .feature_note)`, try changing the property on both `<application>` and `<activity>` tags to something like:
`android.example.noteapp` & `android.example.mainActivity`

Comment: that worked nicely